# Python column mean based on other column conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to return the average of a column values based on a condition of another column.

Here is a sample dataframe

```
Day   count   pay    
1      0      5.25
2      0      7.21
3      1      9.00 
4      0      11.00
5      2      12.03
```

I want to average the pay column using only the values that have ***count > 0***

My answer in the above case should be 10.515 (9+12.03)/2

This was my version of the code to get the answer but it does not work

```
df[df['count']>0].groupby(['pay']).mean()
```

This code did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this.

```
df[df['count']>0]['pay'].mean()
#10.515
```